# how to access object property for use in api (Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, api, express, object

When i try to access property of object using " . " in my route i am getting error.
Below is the detailed explanation

This is the schema of Story

```
var StorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author:{
       username:{
       type:String
       },
       _id:{
        type:String
       }
     }
})
```

In the api I want to perform search on basis of username of author

```
router.get('/myblogs/:username',function(req,res){
    Story.find({author.username:req.params.username},(err,storys)=>{
        if(err)
        {
            console.log(err)
            res.send({success:false,message:'Something went wrong in storyroute'})
        }
        else{
            response.render('findstory',{storys:storys})
        }
    })
})
```

This code is giving me error if i try to access author.username like this.
What is the correct way to perform query of such types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`author.username` is not a valid javascript syntax as a key name, instead, warp it as a string:

```js
Story.find({ "author.username" : req.params.username}, (err, storys)=> {})
```